# Duplicate Record Issue

Tags: apex, trigger

Here is the problem.

I created a trigger that automatically creates a lead into an opportunity and contact after it is processed.

However, I'm getting the following error message when I try to insert into the contact object:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATES_DETECTED, You're creating a duplicate record.

Below is the source code of my trigger:

```
 trigger conversion on Lead (after insert) {
    set<id>idset=new set<id>();

    list<lead>lelist=new list<lead>();
    account ac=new account();
    contact con=new contact();
    account acs=new account();
    opportunity opp=new opportunity();
    list<account>acclist=new list<account>();

    list<contact>conlist=new list<contact>();
    list<opportunity>opplist=new list<opportunity>();
    if(Trigger.isDelete || Trigger.isInsert){
        if(Trigger.isDelete){
            for(Lead l:trigger.old){

                idset.add(l.id);
                ac.name=l.company;
                ac.id=l.id;

            }
        }
        else {
            for(lead ls:trigger.new){

                idset.add(ls.id);
                ac.name=ls.company;


            }
        }
    }
    for(lead le:trigger.new){

        idset.add(le.id);
        ac.name=le.company;
        opp.leadsource=le.leadsource;
        con.leadsource=le.leadsource;  
        con.lastname=le.lastname;
        con.firstname=le.firstname;
        con.phone=le.phone;
        con.mailingstreet=le.street;
        con.mailingcity=le.city;
        con.mailingstate=le.state;
        con.mailingpostalcode=le.postalcode;



    }
         acclist.add(ac);
    insert acclist;





    for(account acc:acclist){   

        con.accountid=acc.id;
        opp.name=acc.name;
        opp.stagename='Closed Won';
        opp.closedate=system.today();
        opp.accountid=acc.id;  

    }

    conlist.add(con);
    opplist.add(opp);
    insert conlist;
    insert opplist;
    system.debug('***'+ac);

    }
```

Why am I getting that error even though there are no records of the contact that I'm trying to enter into Salesforce?

Comment: How are you testing it by inserting single lead or in bulk?

Comment: The code doesnt look right to me, it doesnt matter you insert 100 or 200 leads via data loader it will only create one Account and One Opportunity for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DanWooding said, sometimes Dupe Rules catch it. People sometimes set rules for "alert", meaning that the insert is still allowed after a confirmation.

The snippet below replaces the `insert <YourList>` and allows you to insert records despite the validation alerts.

```
    Database.DMLOptions dml = new Database.DMLOptions();
    dml.duplicateRuleHeader.allowSave = true;
    Database.insert(<YourList>, dml);
```

I would not implement this if you want the duplicates to be stopped hard.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Your duplicate rules are catching it. Check Setup -> Administer -> Data Management -> Duplicate Record Sets -> Duplicate Rules.

One of those are firing and flagging it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You have a duplicate rule that is firing. To learn more about duplicate rules. Here is a trailhead unit: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sales_admin_duplicate_management/sales_admin_duplicate_management_unit_1